# How do I match "|" in a regular expression in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, comparison

I want to use a regular expression to filter out if a string contains one of "&" or "|" or "=". I tried:

```
$compareRegex = [String]::Join("|", @("&","|", "="));
"mydfa" -match $compareStr
```

PowerShell prints "True". This is not what I wanted, and it seems "|" itself has confused PowerShell for a matching. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

@Kayasax answer would do in this case (thus +1), just wanted to suggest more general solution.

First of all: you are not using the pattern that you've just created. I suspect `$compareStr` is `$null`, thus it will match anything.

To the point: if you want to create pattern that will match characters/strings and you can't predict if any of them will be/contain special character or not, just use `[regex]::Escape()` for any item you want to match against:

```
$patternList = "&","|", "=" | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }
$compareRegex = $patternList -join '|'
"mydfa" -match $compareRegex
```

In such a case input can be dynamic, and you won't end up with pattern that matches anything.

Answer (score 3):

The `|` has a special meaning in regular expressions. Alternations (lists of alternative matches) are separated by this character. For instance, the expression

```
a|b|c
```

would match either `a` or `b` or `c`.

For matching a literal `|` you need to escape it with backslash (`\|`) or put it in a character class (`[|]`), so your expression should look like this:

```
"mydfa" -match "\||&|="
```

or like this:

```
"mydfa" -match "[|&=]"
```